# Tensorflow : How to recover a tensor properly

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, restore

Sorry for this newbie question, but i have some trouble learning tensor flow. I know basic things about ML ( linear regression, nn, cnn, perceptron, Kmeans ..) but i did not have any experience on a particular library.

I'm currently learning how to save and recover datas from a graph.
In my example, i do have a tensor which shape is equal to [168,8,8] It has been named **saved_tensor**

But i don't know how to recover it properly, below what i've done so far.
As you will see, it is working when shape is constant and as you would imagine, shape can be in the form [x,8,8]

1. Can please someone guide me on this ?
   I believe i have to dig into reshaping (which i did btw) but i don't know how to modify simple code below.
2. Could you please recommend a
   practical guide on Tensorflow (other that official documentation
   which i found a bit hard to learn) (Saw upcoming books Delip
   Rao/Tensorflow or Jordi Torres/First Contact With Tensorflow)

> ```
>     t = tf.zeros((168,8,8),tf.double)
>     ten = tf.Variable(t, name="saved_tensor")
>
>     saver = tf.train.Saver()
>     with tf.Session() as sess:
>         saver.restore(sess, Path)
>         print("Model restored.")
>         print(ten.eval())
>         # sth else to do #
> ```

Regards,
Pierre

Have found the following site to learn tensorflow from the start :http://learningtensorflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the Variable without an initial value, and with validate_shape=False, and then running the restore process.